# Prevent session id from appearing in browser address bar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config

I have an asp.net application that obviously uses cookieless session. All he pages displays the session id as part of the URI. I would like to change this. This application was originally built with asp.net 1.1 and has now been converted to asp.net 4.0 with the conversion wizard.

I added the SessionState tag under system.web in order to enforce "cookieless=false". This change has no effect. Can someone tell me where i should be looking?

many thanks in advance

BM

Answer (score 1):

Change cookieless to "UseCookies" to have the session stored inside a cookie. Otherwise the session is embedded into the URL.

Here's more information from the [MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless.aspx)

If you have set cookieless to false in your web.config file and it is still showing the sessionid in url, it means the browser has cookies disabled. Check the browser setting and enable the browser to accept cookies.

There is no way to hide the sessionid if cookies are disabled for a browser.
But there is some work around here:
[Hide Session Id in URL](http://forums.asp.net/t/1656216.aspx/1)

[Reference](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The default is to use cookie session. So just create a new project and copy the session state from the web.config to make sure that it is clean.